# Port ColdFusion Java hashing function to Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, coldfusion, sha256

I'm trying to port a java hashing function to Ruby but keep ending up with a different hash than expected. Below is the relevant java functions (coldfusion):

```
 public string function hashAdministrator(required string pass) {
   MessageDigest = createObject('java','java.security.MessageDigest');
   for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {
     md = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-256');
     md.update(pass.getBytes('UTF-8'));
     pass = enc(md.digest());
   }
   return pass;
 }

 private string function enc(strArr) {
   //local.strArr = str.getBytes('UTF-8');
   local.hex = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

   savecontent variable="local.out" {
     for (local.item in strArr) {
       writeOutput(hex[bitshrn(bitAnd(240,local.item),4)+1]);
       writeOutput(hex[bitAnd(15,local.item)+1]);
     }
   };
   return local.out;
 }
```

Below is my ruby code:

```
 # encoding: utf-8

 require 'digest/sha2'

 class RailoPassword

   attr_accessor :pass

   def admin_password
     password = ''
     5.times do
       md = Digest::SHA2.new
       md.update(self.pass)
       password = self.enc(md.digest.bytes.to_a)
     end
     password
   end


   def enc(strarr)
     hex = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

     a = ''
     strarr.each do |item|
       a << hex[((0xF0 & item) >> 4)]
       a << hex[(0x0F & item)]
     end
     a
   end
 end
```

The actual implementation in ruby:

```
 a = RailoPassword.new
 a.pass = 'test1234'
 puts 'expected: 0be431aeebf55fdc30296e1224fb80b0edbebcddaedb65fcbad1315e906dde65'
 puts "actual:   #{a.admin_password}"
```

Expected hash: `0be431aeebf55fdc30296e1224fb80b0edbebcddaedb65fcbad1315e906dde65`

Returned hash: `937e8d5fbb48bd4949536cd65b8d35c426b80d2f830c5c308e2cdec422ae2244`

The returned hash is the same as if I just got the hex digest from Digest::SHA2:

```
 1.9.3-p547 :335 > Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('test1234')
  => "937e8d5fbb48bd4949536cd65b8d35c426b80d2f830c5c308e2cdec422ae2244"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about you, but if I would inherit code like that, *even from myself* (I've been at it for a long time) I would consider a rewrite. `writeOutput(hex[bitshrn(bitAnd(240,local.item),4)+1]);` lacks clarity in my opinion, especially the `bitAnd` part (what about a constant, `HIGHEST_FOUR_BITS` or `0b1111_0000` in Java?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
def admin_password
    password = ''
    5.times do
        md = Digest::SHA2.new
        md.update(self.pass)
        password = self.enc(md.digest.bytes.to_a)
    end
    password
end
```

does not match your CFML logic. It should be this (I'm a Ruby newbie, so apologies if this ain't perfect Ruby):

```
def admin_password
    # password = '' # get rid of this
    5.times do
        md = Digest::SHA2.new
        md.update(self.pass)
        self.pass = self.enc(md.digest.bytes.to_a) # update the correct variable here
    end
    self.pass # and return the correct variable here
end
```

Having done that, both code blocks return the same value, `0be431aeebf55fdc30296e1224fb80b0edbebcddaedb65fcbad1315e906dde65`

And, to be frank, had you also done what @owlstead had suggested and done some debugging, this would have been immediately apparent to you. So there's a lesson there too: if you ask for help, pay attention to the help that's offered.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at it the wrong way. Wasn't taking into account that it was encoding `self.pass` over the iteration. Much appreciated and lesson learned regarding the debugging. @owlstead, apologies for not reading into it further when you originlly replied.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you do:

```
password = self.pass
```

and then

```
md.update(password)
```

?

Comment: Don't they include debuggers in Ruby? SO is not a community debugger.

Comment: debugging isn't going to tell my why the hash is different than a java function is returning. and no password should not  = self.pass

Comment: Yeah whatever, but in Java you are updating `pass` each loop iteration and you don't in Ruby.

Comment: Debugging by outputting intermediary values whilst your loops work certainly *will* tell you where things start going wrong, and accordingly where to look.